# Ruby on rails templates

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My question might be a bit broad or off the site's topic but I can't help but notice how there's absolutely no website that sells niche rails templates. Why so? I saw a lot of open source projects on github where you can download and use them as your personal website but never saw an actual website that sells them. Is it not allowed to sell Ruby on rails apps or is it simply because no one actually ever thought about it?

Comment: While nothing stops you from being able to sell such things the spirit of ruby in general is open source collaboration which is what makes for such a great community.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails is just a framework and it is open-source. You can build any application with it and sell it online. No one will stop you doing so.

Answer (score 0):

It's just with Ruby on Rails, you can use different template languages like: [HAML](http://haml.info), [Slim](http://slim-lang.com) or [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). And you are free to use any Web frameworks like: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com), [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com)…

And finally, each application Ruby on Rails is unique, so you should try to buy a Bootstrap template or another and integrate it to your project.

Comment: Yes, but you still are allowed to sell your templates online?

Comment: Yes, according the license of the technologies you use, you can redistribute or even sell. In case of Ruby on Rails, it's a [MIT license](https://github.com/rails/rails#license), yes you can.